# Declaring and defining C++ arrays at the same time

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am trying at the same time to define and declare some global C++ constants:

In *constants.h*:

```
#ifdef DEFINE_CONSTANTS
#define DECLARE_CONSTANT(DECL_, VAL_) extern DECL_ = VAL_
#else
#define DECLARE_CONSTANT(DECL_, VAL_) extern DECL_
#endif

namespace Constants {
    DECLARE_CONSTANT(const char LABEL[], "SomeText");
    DECLARE_CONSTANT(const int REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);
};
```

In *constants.cpp*:

```
#define DEFINE_CONSTANTS
#include "constants.h"
#undef DEFINE_CONSTANTS
```

In all other files that use the constants I just include *constants.h*

Now, the above works just fine if I do not use array initializers. However, when I try to do something like:

```
DECLARE_CONSTANT(const int ARRAY[], {0,1,2});
```

when compiling *constants.cpp* I get an error since the commas in the initializer "confuse" the preprocessor into thinking  that there are too many parameters to DECLARE_CONSTANT (the exact error depends on compiler).

Is there a trick to deal with this? Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Why are you using the preprocessor. C++ is type safe and has better options

Comment: @EdHeal, please propose your solution

Comment: I have not got a clue as to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a premature optimization that results in a premature pessimization.

- It's an optimization since the memory for the constants is only allocated in one compilation unit. It's true, yet for small constants, like integers, the pointer implied in the use of a variable may be actually larger than the constant itself (say on 64 bit architectures!).
- It is a pessimization since integer constants can't be used as such, they are external constant variables. They won't be subject to constant propagation etc. Your code will be *larger* and will perform *worse*.

What you want is simply:

```
const char LABEL[] = "Some text";
const int REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
```

Those have local linkage. Yes, if you use `LABEL` in multiple places, it will be duplicated in memory and a `strings` dump of the executable will show it.

A non-preprocessor solution takes an `inline` function, since those are not subject to the single definition rule:

```
inline const char * LABEL() { return "Some text"; }
inline const int * ARRAY() { static const int array[] = {0,1,2}; return array; }
const int REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
```

Those won't result in duplicates, unless you take the address of `REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS` in multiple compilation units.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the preprocessor is pretty stupid, and knows nothing about the syntax or constructs of C or C++. So it sees `{0,1,2}` as three different arguments to the macro.

You might be able to use [variadic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) for this though:

```
#define DECLARE_CONSTANT(DECL_, ...) extern DECL_ = __VA_ARGS__
```

Comment: Joachim, while you practically perfectly answer my question, @KubaOber's reply in the end better fits my actual needs. My bad - [Its just what I asked for, but it's not what I want](http://www.poppyfields.net/filks/00227.html) :)

Comment: @malenkiy_scot That's okay, don't worry about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
#define VALUE(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

and then you can use

```
DECLARE_CONSTANT(const int ARRAY[], VALUE({0,1,2}));
```

(Joachim's answer is easier for your specific case, mine is more general)